# I'm trying to create a image classifier machine learning model. while fitting my training data to pipeline, it's showing me this error

Tags: python

the shape of X is

```
X = np.array(X).reshape(len(X),4096).astype(float) 
X.shape
```

**(529, 4096)**

the code

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('svc', SVC(kernel = 'rbf', C = 10))])

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipe.score(X_test, y_test)
```

error

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. StandardScaler expected <= 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need an explanation of what the error message means or how to solve it... but I guess it's both ^^
First, StandardScaler() function accepts 2D NumPy arrays and would fail when processing 3 or more dimensions arrays.
My first guess would have been that you were trying to process some kind of pictures array (like (100, 380, 240, 3)) but as your X.shape returns a 2D array, this is not so obvious.
I would recommend double-checking the X_train and y_train shapes as well, just before you run the pipe.
If their shapes are 2D, you might as well try to apply the StandardScaler() as a stand-alone function to see if this works.

Comment: Yeah! your guess is absolutely correct, I wanted both explanation and solution but as you might have seen my X.shape giving me 2D array and I've tried X_train[0].shape it's giving me this (4096, 1). can you help to resolve this? and of course thank you for your answer(reply).

Comment: The issue I see is that X_train.shape should give a 2D array, not X_train[0].shape. What does X_train.shape outputs?

Comment: Actually X_train  is a list it's giving me the error list object as no attribute shape so i've converted it into np array by using this  => X_train = np.array(X_train) now X_train.shape has value (396, 4096, 1). It's 3d but i don't know how it can be 3d.

Comment: My advice would be to go back to Numpy arrays fundamentals because you should process everything through an array and not use a list for the highest level of your data. May I recommend you to read: https://towardsdatascience.com/better-visualizing-tensors-thanks-to-cities-b97e6b4ca2ca.
And when it comes to your (396, 4096, 1) array, a simple "array.reshape(396, 4096)" would put it back to 2D.